# C# How to get inline xml value Table?

Tags: c#, xml

```
this is xml:

<NewDataSet>
  <xs:schema xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" id="NewDataSet">
    <xs:element msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true" name="NewDataSet">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
          <xs:element name="Table">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" msdata:DateTimeMode="Unspecified" name="A1" type="xs:dateTime"/>
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="X" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Y" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Z" type="xs:string"/>
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
        </xs:choice>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
  </xs:schema>
  <Table>
    <A1/>
    <X>123</X>
    <Y>DDo</Y>
    <Z>Cri</Z>
  </Table>
</NewDataSet>
```

this is my code:

StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(innerDatasetXML);

DataSet newDataset = new DataSet();

newDataset.ReadXml(stringReader, XmlReadMode.IgnoreSchema);

Comment: Yes, this is your code, however, can you elaborate more on what are you expecting ? What went wrong with your code ? What is your expected output ?

Comment: What are you trying to get - the value of each element?

Comment: I want value all in xml tag name <Table>

Comment: @gnfseiei Did you try my answer below?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get values of Table : Element Name + Value:

using System.Xml.Linq;

```
  XElement doc = XElement.Load("path to file or string");
            var results = doc.Descendants("Table").Elements();
            Dictionary<string, string> table = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            
            foreach (XElement ele in results)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ele.Name.ToString() + "=" + ele.Value.ToString());
                table.Add(ele.Name.ToString(), ele.Value);//if needed elsewhere
            }
```